# Run terminal in VS Code in rosetta/intel mode

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, rosetta

A dependency of my code (`pyqt5`) does not run on Apple Silicon:

```
Installing pyqt-qt5 (5.15.2): Failed
RuntimeError
Unable to find installation candidates for pyqt-qt5 (5.15.2)
```

and I'm having difficulties **running the terminal inside VS Code in Rosetta / "Intel mode"**.

I'm using `poetry` to manage and install dependencies.

#### What works: outside of VS Code

I can use conda to manage the virtual environment, and set some environment variables that enforce "Intel mode":

```bash
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n my-intel-env python=3.11 -y
conda activate my-intel-env
conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64
conda deactivate
conda activate my-intel-env
pip install "poetry==1.5.1"
poetry install --with dev
```

`pyqt5` installs without issue:

```bash
...
  • Installing pymiscutils (0.3.14)
  • Installing pyqt5 (5.15.9)
  • Installing requests-oauthlib (1.3.1)
...
```

#### What I've tried: terminal settings

I tried adding a terminal profile in VS Code's `settings.json`:

```json
# settings.json
{
    ...
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.osx": {
        "bash_1": {
            "path": "/opt/homebrew/bin/bash"
        },
        "bash_2": {
            "path": "arch -x86_64 /opt/homebrew/bin/bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
          "path": "/usr/bin/zsh"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

However, this does not work; the profile "bash_2" cannot be selected from the Terminal menu:

[image: Screenshot of the Terminal menu with the missing 'bash_2' option]

#### What I've also tried: running VS Code via Rosetta

I tried to start the Intel version of VS Code, but this does not help; the terminal is a separate process and still does not run via Rosetta.

#### What I can't do: upgrade

I cannot force the dependency to use `pyqt6` instead of `pyqt5`.

Comment: Can you run VSCode via Rosetta?

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot to mention. I can, but the terminal that is spawned is its own process and still does not run via rosetta. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Did you check the VSCode installation whether the terminal is a separate binary?

Comment: PS: Also, please don't paste screenshots of text output. Copy/paste the text instead and format as code to make the content accessible to visually impaired users.

Comment: The terminal path is specified in `settings.json`. Or is that not, what you mean?

Comment: This is the path to `bash`. Terminal would be the component which shows the window `bash` runs in. But I don't know whther this is baked into VSCode or a separate binary within the application folder.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right; `bash` is the shell, and it's run in the internal vscode terminal. It is part of the vscode application and not shown separately in the application folder

Comment: VSCode Settings -> Features -> Terminal allows you to select a terminal application to call. Can you set that to Intel/Rosetta?

Comment: As an alternative pyqt5 can be available in an arm build. In fact you have a larger issue in that to run an intel pyqt5 you need an intel python. In this case this is an issue with PyPi its built wheels only provide an Intel version and unfortunately their lookup provides that for an Apple Silicon machine. Try buildin pyqt5 from source

Comment: I can't directly, but there is a setting to add environment settings (`"terminal.integrated.env.osx" = {}`), and I suspect I can add the correct settings there. I'm unsure about the name and settings I should enter. (For conda, I've found the `CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64` setting, but I don't use it here.)

Comment: Hmmm @mmmmmm that sounds like another headache altogether. Can you give me some pointers, how I'd go about it? I've just completed migrating all my enviroments and dependency management to `poetry`, and now it seems I've stepped on another landmine :/

Comment: With pip et al you can request a package built locally. I don't use poetry so do not know the command but this Issue https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5599 suggests it is possible. How tod actually do this is a question for Stack Overflow. Also conda's qt5 is for wither architecture.

Comment: I've given it some thought and I'm not convinced it's necessary to build the package. I can start alacritty with rosetta and it works fine, I can install and run qt5. The only thing I cannot do is replicate the result in vscode's terminal

Comment: Excuse me, I was mistaken. It's actually not working with alacrity/bash in Rosetta

Comment: I digged a bit further, @mmmmmm. I am able to use conda environments to install pyqt5 without having to build it. See the "What Works" section that I've updated.

Comment: You have now changed this to a different question. However as no votes not much of an issue but please change the titrle. You don't want to be running under Rosetta but you want to get the VSCode setup to use a 'proper' version of pyqt5. I can't help more as I don't use VSCode but I suggest you look at conda integration with VSCode